# How to upload multiple files in angularjs at a time with no browser issues?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-fileupload

I am trying to upload multiple different files at a time using angularjs.

Now the first problem  I am facing is not able to select more than one file before uploading them.Here is the code I am using for selecting multiple files.

```
<input data-ng-class="uploadBar" id="file-browser" type="file" ng-model="ul.files" multiple class="btn btn-default" />
```

when even I am trying to upload second file , its get replaced with first file.

- I want to display on the UI to user what are files he/she has
  selected .
- The user should not select the same file twice, if he/she    tries ,
  error should be displayed.
- During selecting the file , Upload    button should be disabled.
- On selecting and uploading ,I want the    progressbar to be shown on
  screen , how much % file is selected or    uploaded.

Any help is appreciated .Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into something like https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload ?

Comment: Yes , but its too confusing for me , since I am a beginner in angularjs.

Comment: And also the above doc doesnot have the solution which I am looking for .

Comment: Nothing will come right out of the box as you want it, you'll have to extend the functionalities of the plugin to suit your own needs.